# Segmentation Fault--Signal 11

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am relatively new to programming (a few months in) and am trying out some USACO problems. 
When I submitted my program, it said this:

> Run 1: Execution error: Your program (`palsquare') exited with
>           signal #11 (segmentation violation [maybe caused by accessing
>           memory out of bounds, array indexing out of bounds, using a bad
>           pointer (failed open(), failed malloc), or going over the maximum
>           specified memory limit]). The program ran for 0.005 CPU seconds
>           before the signal. It used 2168 KB of memory.

I can't find any dereferenced null pointers, which i initially thought was the problem.

Here is my code (I programmed in C language)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>

int ispal( char *square )
{
    char *temp;

    temp = square + strlen( square ) - 1;
    for( temp = square + strlen( square ) - 1; square < temp; square++, temp-- )
    {
        if( *square != *temp )
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

void convert( char *square, int n, int base )
{
    int len;

    if( n == 0 ) 
    {
        square = "";
        return;
    }

    convert( square, n / base, base );

    len = strlen( square );
    square[len] = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"[n % base];
    square[len + 1] = '\0';
}

int main()
{
    char square[100];
    char temp[100];
    int i, base;
    FILE *fin, *fout;

    fin = fopen( "palsquare.in", "r" );
    fout = fopen( "palsquare.out", "w" );

    fscanf( fin, "%d", &base );
    for( i = 1; i <= 300; i++ ) 
    {
        convert( square, i * i, base );
        if( ispal( square ) ) 
        {
            convert( temp, i, base );
            fprintf( fout, "%s %s\n", temp, square );
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does the program run on your own machine?  Have you tried valgrind or a debugger?

Comment: No, the program crashes and I don't know how to use Dev C++'s debugger (again, I'm pretty new :P)

Comment: Use `strcpy()` to assign strings, not `square = ""`.

Comment: @WhozCraig Since he returns immediately after the assignment, there is no _from that point on_

Comment: @Barmar Ugh. didn't see the return. Thanks for keeping me honest. and `*square = 0;` would seem considerably less overkill than using `strcpy`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `square = ""`, you are changing the value of variable `square` to point to an empty string.

Since this variable is local in function `convert`, changing it has no effect outside the function.

If you want to set the pointed data to an empty string, then use `square[0] = '\0'` instead.

---

By the way, even if it did have effect outside the function somehow (for example, if you used a global variable instead of a local variable), then not only would it not solve the problem, but it would also make things worse:

1. This variable would point to a string, allocated in a memory segment with read-only access permission.
2. This variable would point to an array of characters, allocated in memory to the size of a single character.

As a result of each one of these facts **separately**, any attempt to change the contents at and around the memory address pointed by this variable would most likely yield a memory access violation during runtime.

Comment: `'\0'` is a clearer way to write the `0` in my opinion, to emphasize that it's a string being terminated.